# Smart autocomplete with tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, local-storage, tensorflow.js

Is it possible to build some sort of autocomplete select which suggests values based on previous inputs?
Let’s say I have airport select with 5k items. I would like give user top 5 values to select based on his previous preferences.

Answer (score 0):

**Deep learning approach:**

Basically what you want is an RNN powered word-level prediction model. Such models are used in text generation. You can refer to one example [here](https://link.medium.com/SgH7mYfvpW).

> These models specifically take in a word ( t ) and predict the next word ( t1 ). Then taking t1 it predicts t2. This cycle goes on until the max number of words is reached.

If I had to train such an RNN model on a single sentence like

```
Hello world from TensorFlow
```

Then the feature-label pairs would look like:

```
X, Y
Hello, World
World, from
from, TensorFlow
```

These sentences could be trained from the user's previous inputs.

Things you will require in building such a model:

1. Lots of user data.
2. A ranking algorithm to get the top N predictions
3. Probably, a GPU or TPU. CPUs might prove to be very slow and might take days.

**Non-Deep learning approach:**

You can Bayes Theorem or simply check which word has the highest probability after a specific word. The word "morning" will have the highest probability after the word "good".

**Tip:**

- Mostly, you will also need to handle custom user words which you may not add in your dictionary. It could be the name of a person. So while collecting data, you need to tag such words into a common word like .